# Not finding a way to store the files for offline download in the offline web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, offline, service-worker

I'm working on a web application that should work offline.
I'm following "offline first" approach to develop this web application in angular js using service worker specifically "upup" api.
I'm able to cache the html, css, js files and till now it is going good. Now I need to provide a functionality on the web application so that a user should be able to download a file when he is using app offline .
I have study a lots of blogs and also studied "offline cookbook" but not getting any idea of how to implement the offline file download functionality should I store the files in the cache and then user download them when they offline or any other approach will be good?
I have also thought about to store the files in the local db like pouch db but I don't think it would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two options you already listed: storing the file into one of the existing offline storage vaults in the browser or caching it proactively with the Service Worker before the user goes offline.

I would add it to the cache after installing the Service Worker and then return it from the cache when a request comes from the user.

Out of curiosity, what are you making available for offline download? Some PDF?